# Why is Neovim highlighting the cursor line numbers after the cursor has moved off?

Tags: line-numbers

I have turned on `CursorLineNr` highlighting as shown in this `init.vim` file. When I have my cursor on a line that wraps, it highlights all the individual "lines" on that line, as usual. However once my cursor leaves that line, it keeps the other lines other than the first highlighted. In the picture below, I had moved my cursor down through every line and then back up. You can see the grey boxes that remain when my cursor went over those lines. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Could someone please help?

[image: highlighted area on line wrap]